# What is the integral used in this notation?

Tags: measure-theory

The following integral is from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Regular_conditional_probability&oldid=753857167). What is the integral used here? Is it Lebesgue? But doesnt Lebesgue integral have a measure after d, so it is sth like $\int f dP$ where P is a measure?
Or is it Lebesgue stieltjes integral? But doesnt lebesgue stieltjes have a distribution function after d? so it is sth like $\int f dQ$ where Q is a distribution function?

What is this?

$$P{\big (}A\cap T^{{-1}}(B){\big )}=\int _{B}\nu (x,A)\,P{\big (}T^{{-1}}(dx){\big )}.$$

Comment: See jgon's answer below. In general, $\int f(x)\,\mu({\rm d}x)$ is another notation for $\int f(x)\,{\rm d}\mu(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$P(T^{-1}(dx))$ is alternative notation for $dT_*P(x)$, where $T_*P$ is the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) of $P$ along $T$. So they mean Lebesgue integral here.

In general $\mu(dx)$ is alternative notation for $d\mu(x)$.